Internal Server error when trying API calls to AKS service
I have a managed azure API service that is connected to a test pod. When I try to send API calls to the service, I get a 500 error.
I have my deployment defined like this:
deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:  my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: testingcontainer.azurecr.io/my-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000

I have defined my service type to be a loadbalancer so I can call it from external IPs
service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: my-app

I have port 3000 exposed on my docker file too.
What I have tried
Checking container logs: There is no record of any funny business happening inside the container.
I made sure the app labels and the service labels are the same.
I tried to change the port configuration on my managed azure API.
What could I be missing?
Edit
Dockerfile
FROM node:18.13.0-slim

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]


By Azure API I mean azure API Management Service

How did use azure API service? what type of code you used in azure API service? I see docker image use how to use configure azure API service with image?

Refer to  link Deploy API Management in front of AKS  option

use  http://<external-ip>/weatherforecast/  http://<external-ip>/endpoint

are you asing nginx ? please share docker file ?  using vpn?

what do mean  azure API? does it mean  API Management

No, I am neither using nginx nor a vpn

can you share the api code as well

by api code, do you mean api management service configurations?

haa yes ,  @Nnaobi

I am not sure what exactly you want me to send. When I trace I get the error An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions


The 500 Internal Server Error can occur due to various issues related to the server, application, or configuration.

Refer to this article on using API Management in an Azure Kubernetes cluster with Docker.
Deployment YAML:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: nginx:1.7.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "50Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "500m"


Service YAML:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true" 
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: api


When using an existing Azure API Management, you need to leverage the Self-hosted Gateway feature, which is available in the Developer or Premium tiers, to establish a connection.
To set up an Azure API Management self-hosted gateway connected to a Kubernetes test pod, you'll require a combination of Kubernetes configuration files, secrets, and a Docker container for the self-hosted gateway.
Refer to the following Additional resources:

To Docker Integration with Azure API Management using  Self-hosted Gateway  and deploy a self-hosted gateway to Kubernetes with YAML



